# Problems with fancy style and KOMA-Script

Tags: koma-script, fancyhdr

I would like to write an article with "Koma-Script" and use the "fancy page style". Therefore, I use the following commands before beginning the document:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, spanish, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment 
this line to return to the LaTeX default

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages

\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers

\usepackage{fancylabel}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{caption} 

\usepackage{subfigure} 

\usepackage{flushend}

\usepackage{mathtext}

\usepackage{epsfig}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}

\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\rightmark}}
```

When I compile the programm it makes the PDF, but the sections and the table of contents are not highlighted in bold. Moreover, the programm produce the following error:

> Usage of package `fancyhdr' together(scrartcl) with a KOMA-Script class is not > recommended.
>
> incompatible usage of \@ssect detected.
>
> incompatible usage of \@ssect detected.
>
> incompatible usage of \@ssect detected.

P.S.The programm I use in order to write and compile in LaTeX is: "TeXstudio"

I have looked for the whole warning message and i found it:

> Class scrartcl Warning: incompatible usage of \@ssect detected.
>
> (scrartcl)               You've used the KOMA-Script implementation of \@ssect
>
> (scrartcl)               from within a non compatible caller, that does not
>
> (scrartcl)               \scr@s@ct@@nn@m@ locally.
>
> (scrartcl)               This could result in several error messages on input line 85.

This line is where I wrote the `\tableofcontents`, and in the Pdf it is not in bold as it has to be.

Comment: Yes, the message is pretty clear, isn't it? Either don't use `KOMA`, but a standard class instead or drop `fancyhdr` and use `scrlayer-page` in order to get the page headers etc. I am also wondering about `sectsty` and `KOMA` here

Comment: The `subfigure` package is totally deprecated, use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead

Comment: The same is true for `epsfig` .... :-(

Comment: BTW: Loading packages more than once isn't an error but nevertheless you should not do it. Seems you are using an awful template or an outdated manual or something like this. And the warning messages are longer than shown. Maybe your editor shows only a part of it. Have a look into the `.log`-file to get more information.

Comment: However: Warning messages are warnings *not* errors. They show things, that *could* result in a problem. Without a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) we cannot see whether or not you have any problem (other than some—maybe unwanted—warning messages). If there are other problems, specify and especially [show them](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 4):

If you use package `fancyhdr` with a KOMA-Script class you will get the warning:

> Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr` together
>   with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. I'd suggest to use package `scrlayer` or `scrlayer-scrpage`, because they support KOMA-Script classes. With `fancyhdr` several features of class `scrartcl` like options `headsepline`, `footsepline` or command`\MakeMarkcase` and the commands `\setkomafont` and`\addtokomafont` for the page style elements need explicite user intervention to work.

Note that this is only a **warning** and not an error message. So if you understand that some KOMA-Script features and commands for page header and footer will not work with this package, you can load it and define your page headers and footers with it.

But package `fancyhdr` does not effect the font of the section headings inside the text body.

Loading the package `sectstyle` with a KOMA-Script class results in warnings

> Class scrartcl Warning: incompatible usage of `\@ssect` detected. You've used the KOMA-Script implementation of `\@ssect`from within a non compatible caller, that does not `\scr@s@ct@@nn@m@` locally.

at least for `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. Note that KOMA-Script has its own commands for changing the font settings or the alignment of section titles. So do not use package `sectsty` or `titlesec`.

But loading the package `sectsty` does still not unbold the section titles as you can see in the following example (unrelated packages are removed):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{sectsty}% <- only for the example - do not use this package with a KOMA-Script class!!
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% <- replacing by scrlayer-scrpage suggested
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\rightmark}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{A section}
Text
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

So I guess: there must be either one of the `sectsty` commands `\allsectionfonts` or `\sectionfont` or one of the KOMA-Script commands `\setkomafont` or `\addkomafont` changing the settings for one of the font elements `disposition` or `section` in your document. All of them can unbold the section titles, but unfortunaly there was no MWE in your question showing your settings.